# Natural plugin in Eclipse is not providing ctrl+click option

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

I have been using Natural plugin in Eclipse to edit my Gherkin feature files. It was working perfectly fine, but all of suddenly ctrl+click is not working, it is supposed to take to the step definition method. I'm using Eclipse Oxygen version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to move away from Natural plugin. It doesn't work perfectly in recent days.

You can un-install Natural plugin and install "Cucumber Eclipse" plugin. You can search for "Cucumber" in eclipse market place, and it would appear in the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, in "Help" >> "Install New Software...", use httpS:
https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural

Keywords: Eclipse cucumber plugin, Gherkin, natural.

Answer (score 0):

They changed url from http://rlogiacco.github.com/Natural
to http://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural

Try io one and it will work :)